# Including .eps pictures in Windows 10 Texworks

Tags: pdftex, windows, linux

I have a problem with Texworks on Windows 10.

I want to include graphs as .eps files isntead of .png. Now, when I try to compile my document into a PDF, I get the error message:

"____________________

```
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `PICTURES/kdiss_molCN-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found: using draft setting.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

"_____________________

The file i was trying to compile is, as a minized example:

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}


\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%% REQUIRED PACKAGES
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb} % math stuff
\usepackage{booktabs} % better layout for tables
\usepackage{color} % enable use of colors
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % definition of own headers/footers
\usepackage{graphicx} % for including pictures
\usepackage{units} % for giving quantities the right surrounding
\usepackage{xspace} % correct spacing behind DuMuX command

%% OPTIONAL PACKAGES
\usepackage{array} % needed for the new column type
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text with \lipsum[1]
\usepackage{subcaption} % multiple figures in one row
\usepackage{rotating} % rotating of figures
\usepackage{todonotes} % for colorful todo notes
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=2]{hyperref} % enable links


\begin{document}
Hi

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{PICTURES/kdiss_molCN.eps}
    \caption[$k_{diss}$:Molare Konzentration Cyanid, Oberfläche] {Molare Konzentration von Cyanid an der Oberfläche für verschiedene Werte von $k_{\mathrm{diss}}$}
    \label{2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

Is there a solution? Because on my OpenSuse system it worked, so the problem has to be with Windows 10.

Comment: you need to have ghostscript installed to convert the eps to pdf or (better) save the files as pdf rather than eps

Comment: you do not need to load `epsfig` or `epstopdf` packages, the first is just for compatibility with a syntax used in the1980s and the second is automatically loaded if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I installed Ghostscript, how do I make it convert them? Cause I'd rather not save all of them as pdf, that would be some effort to convert and save them all

Comment: Also, isn't .eps higher quality vs .pdf files?

Comment: no, the eps is converted to pdf before being included by pdflatex in anycase, if you make the pdf yourself you can control the pdf, otherwise pdflatex will call ghostscript to convert it (which is why you need ghostscript) pdflatex itself can not include eps files.

Comment: if ghostscript is in your path then the epstopdf script should run automatically with your original example and produce `PICTURES/kdiss_molCN-eps-converted-to.pdf`

Comment: Hm, I put all the Ghostscript folders in the PICTURES folder and it still doesn't work. It should be on the path since it uses pictures from that folder.

Comment: no you need the executable to be in the system PATH enviornment variable I think (I don't use the windows build, someone else will have to confirm the details)

Comment: Oh, ok. How do I find out where the path is, aka where I can paste the .exe and have it work?

Comment: Weird, I gotit to work when I copied everything to the desktop and ran the simplified version after  a couple of tries. It works now. I did the same thing with the actual one and I still get the same error, This shit is weird.